# Trigger Show Modal Popup in Razor Page OnPost Model method

Tags: razor, .net-core, bootstrap-modal, razor-pages

I am trying to open a modal popup after the `OnPost` method is called in my razor page but I can't find the best solution for my specific use case.

In my Razor Page I have a couple of text fields and a "Search" button that when clicked look for data in my DB based on the text the user wrote in the text boxes. At this point I fetch the data from the DB and load it into a list that is then passed to a partial view contained in my modal popup, by inspecting the HTML in my browser it populates it correctly.
What I am missing is the next step and showing the modal popup. I tried setting some bind properties to edit the modal attributes but that didn't work (I know, it is not the most elegant solution).

Bellow is a snippet of my code:

Razor Page:

```
@page
@model Namespace.ResponderSchemaModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Responder Schema";
}

<form method="post">
    <div class="md-form input-group">
        <input type="tel" id="phone" name="phone" placeholder="Phone" />
        <input type="tel" id="responder" name="responder" placeholder="Responder" />
        <div class="input-group-append">
            <button class="btn btn-sm btn-red waves-effect m-0 px-3" type="submit" id="searchButton" asp-page-handler="SearchResponder">Search</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>

<div class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" id="details-modal">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title">Responders Found</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                @if (Model.Responders.Count > 1)
                {
                <partial name="_ResponderSearch" model="Model.Responders" />
                }
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Page Model:

```
public class ResponderSchemaModel : PageModel
{
    [BindProperty]
    public List<Object> Responders { get; set; }

    public void OnPostSearchExchange(string phone, string responder)
    {
        Responders = // Gets the data from the DB.
    }
}
```

Partial View:

```
@model List<Object>

<table id="searchResultTable" class="display nowrap table-sm table-striped table-hover table-bordered" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Nnumber</th>
            <th>Sip</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
        {
        <tr>
            <td>@Model[i].Name</td>
            <td>@Model[i].Description</td>
            <td>@Model[i].Uri</td>
        </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Bootstrap modal can be activated by JavaScript. You can use client side script to detect if the partial has been rendered, and show the modal if it has:

```
@section scripts{
    <script>
    $(function(){
        if($('#searchResultTable').length > 0){
            $('#details-modal').modal('show');
        }
    });
    </script>
}
```

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/#via-javascript

Comment: Thanks, that was what I was looking for!